# Extract file_name.zip.001 via Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to extract file_name.zip.001 on a Linux host which I connect to via PuTTY.

Could you please suggest me how to extract those files?

Comment: PuTTY is just the way you go to the server. It is not a tool for extracting.

Comment: ok glglgl. could you please suggest me to extract file_name.zip.001 on server..

Comment: See Louis's solution: with `unzip` it should work. Except if the file is part of a bigger archive, then you should try to get the missing part. `file file_name.zip.001` might give you a hint if it really is a zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna use the unzip console command.

`man unzip` will show you how.

By the way - That's got nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: if it is zip files means, we can use unzip in linux command. but stil i am getting confusion to extract zip.001..

Comment: Have you already tried it? *.zip.001 normally indicates that it is just a part of a bigger, splitted zip archive.